# Problems with Makeindex

Tags: nomenclature

I use TeXnicCenter and I want to create a nomenclature and I watched a tutorial video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ss1XfsaAnfs)

I did everything exactly as it is told in this tutorial video. Exspecially I had to change the argument for MakeIndex to : `makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg`

Here is my example code

```
 \listfiles
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}
\usepackage{nomencl}
 \makeindex
\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation*}
s = v * t
\end{equation*}

\nomenclature{$s$}{Strecke}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

I also tried without the comment `\makeindex`. When I want to compile the MakeIndex I get the error message:

> Couldn't find input index file makeindex nor makeindex.idx

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I've editted your code to improve the formatting a little.

Answer (score 3):

The command name is `\makenomenclature`, not `\makeindex`. The latter is for the index, the former for the nomenclature.

When restricted shell escape is enabled, the call of `makeindex` can also be put into the TeX file:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}

\immediate\write18{%
  makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls -t \jobname.nlg \jobname.nlo%
}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\begin{document}

TEST
\begin{equation*}
s = v * t
\end{equation*}

\nomenclature{$s$}{Strecke}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]