# Nomenclature not shown in document

Tags: nomenclature

I have a new problem with the nomenclature. My preamble in the main file has the following lines:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,draft,table*]{sdqthesis}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\immediate\write18{%
  makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls -t \jobname.nlg \jobname.nlo%
} 
.
.
.
```

And in the same main file I use the command:

> \printnomenclature

Then in another file, which is inculded in the main file, I define after an equation:

```
\nomenclature{$P^{NOpt}$}{Elektrische Leistung der nicht optimierbaren Geräte}
```

After compiling no error message is show but the nomenclature cannot be found anywhere. Does anyone have a clue what I have to do.

[Problems with Makeindex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262108/problems-with-makeindex/269795#269795)

I was adviced  to post a new question with a link to the other question.

Comment: Please transfer the real question to this place -- the link to a non-answer which is likely to be deleted isn't really useful

Comment: Have you checked that `makeindex` had created file `*.nls` and do the files `*.nlo` and `*.nlg`exist?

Comment: my arguments for the latex compiler are:
-max-print-line=120 -interaction=nonstopmode  -shell-escape "%wm"
and to make index:
makeindex %.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o %.nls -t %.nlg
But the nomenclature is still  not displayed

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be some asynchronous IO between the closing of the `.nlo` file (which contains the nomenclature entries) and the call to the shell-escape.

I've defined a command `\writenomcl{\jobname}` and hooked it into `\AtEndDocument`, so after two runs of `pdflatex` etc. the entries should be there.

The key point is to postpone the writing, i.e. `\write18` and `\closeout` without `\immediate`.

```
\documentclass{article} % Don't have this sdqthesis.cls
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\closenomencl}{%
  \closeout\@nomenclaturefile%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\writenomencl}[1]{%
  \closenomencl%
  \IfFileExists{#1.nlo}{%
    \write18{%
      makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o #1.nls -t #1.nlg #1.nlo%
    }% 
  }{\typeout{Nothing there}}%
}


\AtEndDocument{\writenomencl{\jobname}}

\begin{document}

\nomenclature{$P^{NOpt}$}{Elektrische Leistung der nicht optimierbaren Geräte}
\nomenclature{$\lambda$}{Wellenlänge}

Hello World


\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I eliminated the command: "\immediate" from the main file. Now I have the following command in the mail file: "\write18{%
  makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls -t \jobname.nlg \jobname.nlo%
}" But still no nomenclature in the document

Comment: I think you have to close the `.nlo` file (like I've done in my code)

Comment: Okay, now it works. Is there a way how I can change the heading from Nomenclature into the german word Nomenklatur?