# Nomenclature too long?

Tags: nomenclature

I am currently trying to add a nomenclature to my document. At the beginning I had the problem that the nomenclature was not displayed at all in the document. (Here is a link to a question which I posted in this forum: [Nomenclature not shown in document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269804/nomenclature-not-shown-in-document))

Then I fixed the problem and everything was okay. But suddenly after having added some 40 entries into the nomenclature I cannot add new entries. I use exactly the same commands but the new enties are not displayed in the document. Could anyone think of a possible reason for that? Might my nomenclature be too long?

Here is a compileable file with my commands:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\closenomencl}{%
  \closeout\@nomenclaturefile%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\writenomencl}[1]{%
  \closenomencl%
  \IfFileExists{#1.nlo}{%
    \write18{%
      makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o #1.nls -t #1.nlg #1.nlo%
    }% 
  }{\typeout{Nothing there}}%
}


\AtEndDocument{\writenomencl{\jobname}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenklatur}



\begin{document}




\nomenclature{$P^{ESG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des einmalig startbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby-init}$}{Anfänglicher Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby}$}{Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_j(t_r)$}{Funktion für die Leistungsabgabe des Gerätes $j$ relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$t$}{Absolute Systemzeit}
\nomenclature{$t_r$}{Relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$r_j$}{Freigabezeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$s_j$}{Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$; angegeben in Bezug auf den frühestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$p_j$}{Dauer des Programms von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$d_j$}{Spätestmöglicher Zeitpunkt an dem das Programm von Gerät $j$ beendet sein muss}
\nomenclature{$tDoF_j$}{Zeitlicher Freiheitsgrad des Gerätes $j$}

\nomenclature{$P^{ESG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des einmalig startbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby-init}$}{Anfänglicher Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby}$}{Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_j(t_r)$}{Funktion für die Leistungsabgabe des Gerätes $j$ relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$t$}{Absolute Systemzeit}
\nomenclature{$t_r$}{Relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$r_j$}{Freigabezeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$s_j$}{Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$; angegeben in Bezug auf den frühestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$p_j$}{Dauer des Programms von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$d_j$}{Spätestmöglicher Zeitpunkt an dem das Programm von Gerät $j$ beendet sein muss}
\nomenclature{$tDoF_j$}{Zeitlicher Freiheitsgrad des Gerätes $j$}


\nomenclature{$P^{UG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des unterbrechbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,l} (t_{r,l})$}{Funktion für die elektrische Leistung der Phase $l$ des Programms vom unterbrechbaren Gerät $j$ zur relativen Zeit $t_{r,l}$ }
\nomenclature{$s_{j,i} $}{Relativer Startzeitpunkt der Phase $i$ des Programms von Gerät $j$. Angegeben in Bezug auf den frühestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$p_{j,i}$}{Dauer der Phase $i$ des Programms von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$l$}{Phasenindex}
\nomenclature{$i$}{Phasenindex}
\nomenclature{$t_{r,l}$}{Relative Zeitangabe in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt der Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$n_j$}{Anzahl der Phasen des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$J^{NOpt}$}{Menge aller nichtoptimierbarer Geräte}
\nomenclature{$J^{UG}$}{Menge aller unterbrechbarer Geräte}

\nomenclature{$P^{BOUG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des beliebig oft unterbrechbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Run}$}{Konstante Leistung des Gerätes $j$ im Betriebsmodus}
\nomenclature{$p_{j,max}$}{Maximale Laufzeit einer Phase von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$p_{j,min}$}{Minimale Laufzeit einer Phase von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$s_{j,min}$}{Minimale Zeit im Standby-Modus von Gerät $j$}

\nomenclature{$Q_j^{a_j}(t_r)$}{Funktion für die elektrische Leistung des Profils $a_j$ von Gerät $j$ zum relativen Zeitpunkt $t_r$}
\nomenclature{$p_j^{a_j}$}{Dauer des Programms von Profil $a_j$ des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$a_j$}{Entscheidungsvariable des Geräts $j$ für die Auswahl des Profils bzw. der Leistungsstufe}
\nomenclature{$k_j$}{Anzahl der verschiedenen Profile für das Programm von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$J^{ESLFG}$}{Menge aller einmalig startbarer lastprofilflexibler Geräte}

\nomenclature{$Q_{j,l}^{a_{j,l}} (t_{r,l})$}{Funktion für die elektrische Leistung des Profils ${a_{j,l}}$ der Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$ zum relativen Zeitpunkt $t_{r,l}$}
\nomenclature{$p^{a_{j,l}}_{j,i}$}{Dauer des Profils ${a_{j,l}}$ der Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$k_{j,l}$}{Anzahl der verschiedenen Profile für die Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$a_{j,l}$}{Entscheidungsvariable des Gerätes $j$ für die Auswahl des Profils bzw. der Leistungsstufe in Phase $l$}
\nomenclature{$J^{ULFG}$}{Menge aller unterbrechbarer lastprofilflexibler Geräte}       

\nomenclature{$J^{BOULFG}$}{Menge aller beliebig oft unterbrechbarer lastprofilflexibler Geräte}    

\nomenclature{$G^{BHKW}_j(t)$}{Gasverbrauch des BHKWs $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}    
\nomenclature{$E^{BHKW}_j(t)$}{Vom BHKW $j$ gelieferte Wärmenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}   
\nomenclature{$g_{j,Start} $}{Konstante Menge an verbrauchtem Gas während der Anlaufphase des BHKWs $j$}    
\nomenclature{$g_{j,Run}$}{Menge an verbrauchtem Gas während des normalen Betriebes des BHKWs $j$}  
\nomenclature{$h_{j,Run}$}{Vom BHKW $j$ gelieferte konstante Wärmenergie während des Betriebes}     
\nomenclature{$H_s$}{Brennwert von Gas} 
\nomenclature{$\eta_{j,Th}$}{Thermischer Wirkungsgrad von Gerät $j$}    
\nomenclature{$\eta_{j,el}$}{Elektrischer Wirkungsgrad von Gerät $j$}

\nomenclature{$G^{BWK}_j(t)$}{Gasverbrauch des Brennwertkessels $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$g^{a_{j,l}}_{j,l}$}{Verbrauchte Gasmenge der Leistungsstufe a_{j,l} des Brennwertkessels $j$ in Phase $l$  }
\nomenclature{$E^{BWK}_j(t)$}{Vom Brennwertkessel $j$ gelieferte Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$h^{a_{j,l}}_{j,l}$}{gelieferte Wärmenergie der Leistungsstufe a_{j,l} des Brennwertkessels $j$ in Phase $l$ }

\nomenclature{$E_{Klimaanlage,j} (t)$}{Von der Klimaanalge $j$ gelieferte Kühlenergie (dem Raum entnommene Wärmeenergie) zum Zeitpunkt t}
\nomenclature{$c^{a_{j,l}}_{j,l}$}{Kühlenergie der Kühlenergiestufe ${a_{j,l}}$ in Phase $l$ der Klimaanlage $j$}
\nomenclature{$EER_j$}{\textit{Energy Efficiency Ratio} der Klimaanlage $j$}

\nomenclature{$P^{BL} (t)$}{Elektrische Leistung der Beleuchtungsanlage zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
%\nomenclature{$\Phi^{BL} (t)$}{Lichtstrom der Beleuchtungsanlage zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
%\nomenclature{$\phi_{l}^{a_l}$}{Lichtstrom der Leistungsstufe ${a_l}$ der Beleuchtungsanlage in Phase $l$ }
\nomenclature{$t_{opt}$}{Optimierungshorizont}
\nomenclature{$t_1$}{}
\nomenclature{$t_l$}{Zeitliche Ausdehnung von den gleichlangen Phasen der Beleuchtungsanlage}

\nomenclature{$K_{el}(t)$}{Stromkosten zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$P_{ges}^{EZ} (t)$}{Gesamte erzeugte elektrische Energie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$P_{ges}^V (t)$}{Gesamte verbrauchte elektrische Energie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$J^{V}$}{Menge aller Geräte, die Strom verbrauchen}
\nomenclature{$p_{el} (t)$}{Zeitvariabler Stromtarif}
\nomenclature{$J^{EZ}$}{Menge aller Geräte, die Strom erzeugen}
\nomenclature{$P_U  (t)$}{Überschussenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$p_{EZ,j}$}{konstanter Einspeisetarif für das stromerzeugende Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$P_{j}^{EZ} (t)$}{Erzeugte elektrische Energie von Gerät $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{${P_{j}^V} (t)$}{Verbrauchte elektrische Energie von Gerät $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}

\nomenclature{$K_{Gas} (t)$}{Gaskosten für den Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$G_{Ges}(t)$}{Gesamte Menge an verbrauchten Gas zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$p_{Gas}$}{Konstanter Gaspreis}
\nomenclature{$J^{GV}$}{Menge aller Geräte, die Gas verbrauchen}    
\nomenclature{$G^{GV}_j(t)$}{Gasverbrauch von Gerät $j$ zum Zeitpukt $t$}   

\nomenclature{$K_S(t)$}{Kosten für die Überschreitung der Lastgrenze zum Zeitpunkt (t)} 
\nomenclature{$L_{el} (t)$}{Zeitvariables Lastbegrenzungssignal}    
\nomenclature{$P_{UL} (t)$}{Menge an Energie, die zur Überschreitung der Lastgrenze führt}  
\nomenclature{$K_{Ges}$}{Gesamtkosten}  
\nomenclature{$S$}{Straffunktion für die Überschreitung der Lastgrenze}

\nomenclature{$EM (t)$}{CO\textsubscript{2}-Emissionen zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$P_R (t)$}{Resultierender Bedarf an elektrischer Energie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$em_{Gas}$}{Zeitvariables CO\textsubscript{2}-Signal}
\nomenclature{$em_{Gas}$}{Konstante CO\textsubscript{2}-Emissionen von Gas}
\nomenclature{$EM_{Ges}$}{Gesamten CO\textsubscript{2}-Emissionen}

\nomenclature{$DK_{Th}(t)$}{Thermischer Diskomfort zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{uLimit}$}{Unteres Temperaturlimit für minimalen thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$T_{oLimit}$}{Oberees Temperaturlimit für minimalen thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$T_{In} (t)$}{Raumtemperatur zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$S_{Th}$}{Straffunktion für den thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$DK_{Th,Ges}$}{Gesamter thermischer Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$T_{\varnothing}^{min}$}{Minimal zulässige Durchschnittstemperatur}
\nomenclature{$T_{\varnothing}$}{Durchschnittstemperatur}
\nomenclature{$T_{\varnothing}^{max}$}{Maximal zulässige Durchschnittstemperatur}

\nomenclature{$DK_{Vi}(t)$}{Visueller Diskomfort zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},uLimit}$}{Untere Grenze für die Beleuchtungsstärke für minimalen visuellen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$E_\text{v,Ges} (t)$}{Gesamte Beleuchtungsstärke zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},oLimit}$}{Obere Grenze für die Beleuchtungsstärke für minimalen visuellen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$S_{Vi}$}{Straffunktion für den thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$E_\text{v,Kunstlicht} (t)$}{Beleuchtungsstärke des Kunstlichtes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_\text{v,Tageslicht} (t)$}{Beleuchtungsstärke des Tageslichtes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$A_{Beleuchtet}$}{Beleuchtete Fläche}
\nomenclature{$DK_{Vi,Ges}$}{Gesamter visueller Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},\varnothing}^{min}$}{Minimal zulässige durchschnittliche Beleuchtungsstärke}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},\varnothing}$}{Durchschnittliche Beleuchtungsstärke}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},\varnothing}^{max}$}{Maximal zulässige durchschnittliche Beleuchtungsstärke}

\nomenclature{$AS$}{Anzahl der Startsvorgänge}
\nomenclature{$E_{Verlust} (t)$}{Verlustwärme des Gebäudes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
%\nomenclature{$\Delta T$}{Temperaturdifferenz}
\nomenclature{$A$}{Nutzfläche des Gebäudes}
\nomenclature{$k_{Verlust}$}{Proportionalitätskonstante für die Verlustwärme des Gebäudes}
\nomenclature{$T_{Au"s en} (t)$}{Außentemperatur zum Zeitpunkt (t)}
\nomenclature{$E_{NW} (t)$}{Benötigte Wärmenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{Soll}$}{Festgelegte Soll-Temperatur}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Etagenhöhe}
%\nomenclature{$\rho_{Luft}$}{Dichte von Luft}
\nomenclature{$c_{Luft}$}{Spezifische Wärmekapazität von Luft}
\nomenclature{$E_{Diff} (t)$}{Wärmeenergiedifferenz des Gebäudes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{Heizung} (t)$}{Von der Heizung gelieferte Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{Klimaanlage} (t)$}{Von der Klimaanlage dem Gebäude entnommene Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{Sonstige} (t)$}{Vom menschlichen Körper und von den Haushaltsgeräten abgegebene Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{max}$}{Maximale von der Heizung lieferbare Wärmeenergie für den Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{WS} (t)$}{Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{WS,Heizen}^{min}$}{Für Heizaktivitäten minimal erforderliche Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{Gasverbrennung} (t)$}{Durch Gasverbrennung verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{Heizung} (t)$}{Durch Heizaktivitäten verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{Warmwasser} (t)$}{Durch den Warmwasserverbrauch verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{VerlustWS} (t)$}{Durch die Verlustwärme verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\rho_{Wasser}$}{Dichte von Wasser}
\nomenclature{$c_{Wasser}$}{Spezifische Wärmekapazität von Wasser}
\nomenclature{$E_{Bereitschaft}(t)$}{Bereitschaftsverlust des Warmwasserspeichers zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$V_{Wassertank}$}{Volumen des Warmwasserspeichers}

\nomenclature{$k_{Bereitschaft}$}{Proportionalitätskonstante für den Bereitschaftsverlust}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{WS}$}{Temperaturdifferenz zwischen Warmwasserspeicher und der Raumtemperatur }
\nomenclature{$T_{WS}^{min}$}{Minimal zulässige Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$T_{WS}^{max}$}{Maximal zulässige Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29702/discussion-on-question-by-noob-nomenclature-too-long).

Answer (score 2):

There are some errors in the file posted by the O.P.

- Package `amssymb` was missing (needed for `\varnothing`)
- Some nomenclature entries have `a_{i,j}` etc without mathmode switch

There will be **no** nomenclature at all if there is no other text printed. This is the same *issue* as with `\printindex` and `\index{...}` commands. If nothing is typeset → no output.

---

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[fixamsmath,disallowspaces]{mathtools}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\closenomencl}{%
  \closeout\@nomenclaturefile%
}
\makeatother


\newcommand{\writenomencl}[1]{%
  \closenomencl%
  \IfFileExists{#1.nlo}{%
    \write18{%
      makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o #1.nls -t #1.nlg #1.nlo%
    }% 
  }{\typeout{Nothing there}}%
}


\AtEndDocument{\writenomencl{\jobname}}
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Nomenklatur}



\begin{document}

Hello darkness my old friend ;-)




\nomenclature{$P^{ESG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des einmalig startbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby-init}$}{Anfänglicher Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby}$}{Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_j(t_r)$}{Funktion für die Leistungsabgabe des Gerätes $j$ relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$t$}{Absolute Systemzeit}
\nomenclature{$t_r$}{Relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$r_j$}{Freigabezeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$s_j$}{Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$; angegeben in Bezug auf den frühestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$p_j$}{Dauer des Programms von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$d_j$}{Spätestmöglicher Zeitpunkt an dem das Programm von Gerät $j$ beendet sein muss}
\nomenclature{$tDoF_j$}{Zeitlicher Freiheitsgrad des Gerätes $j$}

\nomenclature{$P^{ESG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des einmalig startbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby-init}$}{Anfänglicher Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Standby}$}{Standby-Verbrauch des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$Q_j(t_r)$}{Funktion für die Leistungsabgabe des Gerätes $j$ relativ zum Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$t$}{Absolute Systemzeit}
\nomenclature{$t_r$}{Relative Zeit in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$r_j$}{Freigabezeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$s_j$}{Relativer Startzeitpunkt des Gerätes $j$; angegeben in Bezug auf den frühestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$p_j$}{Dauer des Programms von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$d_j$}{Spätestmöglicher Zeitpunkt an dem das Programm von Gerät $j$ beendet sein muss}
\nomenclature{$tDoF_j$}{Zeitlicher Freiheitsgrad des Gerätes $j$}


\nomenclature{$P^{UG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des unterbrechbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,l} (t_{r,l})$}{Funktion für die elektrische Leistung der Phase $l$ des Programms vom unterbrechbaren Gerät $j$ zur relativen Zeit $t_{r,l}$ }
\nomenclature{$s_{j,i} $}{Relativer Startzeitpunkt der Phase $i$ des Programms von Gerät $j$. Angegeben in Bezug auf den frühestmöglichen Startzeitpunkt}
\nomenclature{$p_{j,i}$}{Dauer der Phase $i$ des Programms von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$l$}{Phasenindex}
\nomenclature{$i$}{Phasenindex}
\nomenclature{$t_{r,l}$}{Relative Zeitangabe in Bezug auf den Startzeitpunkt der Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$n_j$}{Anzahl der Phasen des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$J^{NOpt}$}{Menge aller nichtoptimierbarer Geräte}
\nomenclature{$J^{UG}$}{Menge aller unterbrechbarer Geräte}

\nomenclature{$P^{BOUG}_j(t)$}{Elektrische Leistung des beliebig oft unterbrechbaren Gerätes $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$Q_{j,Run}$}{Konstante Leistung des Gerätes $j$ im Betriebsmodus}
\nomenclature{$p_{j,max}$}{Maximale Laufzeit einer Phase von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$p_{j,min}$}{Minimale Laufzeit einer Phase von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$s_{j,min}$}{Minimale Zeit im Standby-Modus von Gerät $j$}

\nomenclature{$Q_j^{a_j}(t_r)$}{Funktion für die elektrische Leistung des Profils $a_j$ von Gerät $j$ zum relativen Zeitpunkt $t_r$}
\nomenclature{$p_j^{a_j}$}{Dauer des Programms von Profil $a_j$ des Gerätes $j$}
\nomenclature{$a_j$}{Entscheidungsvariable des Geräts $j$ für die Auswahl des Profils bzw. der Leistungsstufe}
\nomenclature{$k_j$}{Anzahl der verschiedenen Profile für das Programm von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$J^{ESLFG}$}{Menge aller einmalig startbarer lastprofilflexibler Geräte}

\nomenclature{$Q_{j,l}^{a_{j,l}} (t_{r,l})$}{Funktion für die elektrische Leistung des Profils ${a_{j,l}}$ der Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$ zum relativen Zeitpunkt $t_{r,l}$}
\nomenclature{$p^{a_{j,l}}_{j,i}$}{Dauer des Profils ${a_{j,l}}$ der Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$k_{j,l}$}{Anzahl der verschiedenen Profile für die Phase $l$ von Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$a_{j,l}$}{Entscheidungsvariable des Gerätes $j$ für die Auswahl des Profils bzw. der Leistungsstufe in Phase $l$}
\nomenclature{$J^{ULFG}$}{Menge aller unterbrechbarer lastprofilflexibler Geräte}       

\nomenclature{$J^{BOULFG}$}{Menge aller beliebig oft unterbrechbarer lastprofilflexibler Geräte}    

\nomenclature{$G^{BHKW}_j(t)$}{Gasverbrauch des BHKWs $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}    
\nomenclature{$E^{BHKW}_j(t)$}{Vom BHKW $j$ gelieferte Wärmenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}   
\nomenclature{$g_{j,Start} $}{Konstante Menge an verbrauchtem Gas während der Anlaufphase des BHKWs $j$}    
\nomenclature{$g_{j,Run}$}{Menge an verbrauchtem Gas während des normalen Betriebes des BHKWs $j$}  
\nomenclature{$h_{j,Run}$}{Vom BHKW $j$ gelieferte konstante Wärmenergie während des Betriebes}     
\nomenclature{$H_s$}{Brennwert von Gas} 
\nomenclature{$\eta_{j,Th}$}{Thermischer Wirkungsgrad von Gerät $j$}    
\nomenclature{$\eta_{j,el}$}{Elektrischer Wirkungsgrad von Gerät $j$}

\nomenclature{$G^{BWK}_j(t)$}{Gasverbrauch des Brennwertkessels $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$g^{a_{j,l}}_{j,l}$}{Verbrauchte Gasmenge der Leistungsstufe $a_{j,l}$ des Brennwertkessels $j$ in Phase $l$  }
\nomenclature{$E^{BWK}_j(t)$}{Vom Brennwertkessel $j$ gelieferte Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$h^{a_{j,l}}_{j,l}$}{gelieferte Wärmenergie der Leistungsstufe $a_{j,l}$ des Brennwertkessels $j$ in Phase $l$ }

\nomenclature{$E_{Klimaanlage,j} (t)$}{Von der Klimaanalge $j$ gelieferte Kühlenergie (dem Raum entnommene Wärmeenergie) zum Zeitpunkt t}
\nomenclature{$c^{a_{j,l}}_{j,l}$}{Kühlenergie der Kühlenergiestufe ${a_{j,l}}$ in Phase $l$ der Klimaanlage $j$}
\nomenclature{$EER_j$}{\textit{Energy Efficiency Ratio} der Klimaanlage $j$}

\nomenclature{$P^{BL} (t)$}{Elektrische Leistung der Beleuchtungsanlage zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
%\nomenclature{$\Phi^{BL} (t)$}{Lichtstrom der Beleuchtungsanlage zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
%\nomenclature{$\phi_{l}^{a_l}$}{Lichtstrom der Leistungsstufe ${a_l}$ der Beleuchtungsanlage in Phase $l$ }
\nomenclature{$t_{opt}$}{Optimierungshorizont}
\nomenclature{$t_1$}{}
\nomenclature{$t_l$}{Zeitliche Ausdehnung von den gleichlangen Phasen der Beleuchtungsanlage}

\nomenclature{$K_{el}(t)$}{Stromkosten zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$P_{ges}^{EZ} (t)$}{Gesamte erzeugte elektrische Energie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$P_{ges}^V (t)$}{Gesamte verbrauchte elektrische Energie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$J^{V}$}{Menge aller Geräte, die Strom verbrauchen}
\nomenclature{$p_{el} (t)$}{Zeitvariabler Stromtarif}
\nomenclature{$J^{EZ}$}{Menge aller Geräte, die Strom erzeugen}
\nomenclature{$P_U  (t)$}{Überschussenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$p_{EZ,j}$}{konstanter Einspeisetarif für das stromerzeugende Gerät $j$}
\nomenclature{$P_{j}^{EZ} (t)$}{Erzeugte elektrische Energie von Gerät $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{${P_{j}^V} (t)$}{Verbrauchte elektrische Energie von Gerät $j$ zum Zeitpunkt $t$}

\nomenclature{$K_{Gas} (t)$}{Gaskosten für den Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$G_{Ges}(t)$}{Gesamte Menge an verbrauchten Gas zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$p_{Gas}$}{Konstanter Gaspreis}
\nomenclature{$J^{GV}$}{Menge aller Geräte, die Gas verbrauchen}    
\nomenclature{$G^{GV}_j(t)$}{Gasverbrauch von Gerät $j$ zum Zeitpukt $t$}   

\nomenclature{$K_S(t)$}{Kosten für die Überschreitung der Lastgrenze zum Zeitpunkt (t)} 
\nomenclature{$L_{el} (t)$}{Zeitvariables Lastbegrenzungssignal}    
\nomenclature{$P_{UL} (t)$}{Menge an Energie, die zur Überschreitung der Lastgrenze führt}  
\nomenclature{$K_{Ges}$}{Gesamtkosten}  
\nomenclature{$S$}{Straffunktion für die Überschreitung der Lastgrenze}

\nomenclature{$EM (t)$}{CO\textsubscript{2}-Emissionen zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$P_R (t)$}{Resultierender Bedarf an elektrischer Energie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$em_{Gas}$}{Zeitvariables CO\textsubscript{2}-Signal}
\nomenclature{$em_{Gas}$}{Konstante CO\textsubscript{2}-Emissionen von Gas}
\nomenclature{$EM_{Ges}$}{Gesamten CO\textsubscript{2}-Emissionen}

\nomenclature{$DK_{Th}(t)$}{Thermischer Diskomfort zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{uLimit}$}{Unteres Temperaturlimit für minimalen thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$T_{oLimit}$}{Oberees Temperaturlimit für minimalen thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$T_{In} (t)$}{Raumtemperatur zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$S_{Th}$}{Straffunktion für den thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$DK_{Th,Ges}$}{Gesamter thermischer Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$T_{\varnothing}^{min}$}{Minimal zulässige Durchschnittstemperatur}
\nomenclature{$T_{\varnothing}$}{Durchschnittstemperatur}
\nomenclature{$T_{\varnothing}^{max}$}{Maximal zulässige Durchschnittstemperatur}

\nomenclature{$DK_{Vi}(t)$}{Visueller Diskomfort zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},uLimit}$}{Untere Grenze für die Beleuchtungsstärke für minimalen visuellen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$E_\text{v,Ges} (t)$}{Gesamte Beleuchtungsstärke zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},oLimit}$}{Obere Grenze für die Beleuchtungsstärke für minimalen visuellen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$S_{Vi}$}{Straffunktion für den thermischen Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$E_\text{v,Kunstlicht} (t)$}{Beleuchtungsstärke des Kunstlichtes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_\text{v,Tageslicht} (t)$}{Beleuchtungsstärke des Tageslichtes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$A_{Beleuchtet}$}{Beleuchtete Fläche}
\nomenclature{$DK_{Vi,Ges}$}{Gesamter visueller Diskomfort}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},\varnothing}^{min}$}{Minimal zulässige durchschnittliche Beleuchtungsstärke}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},\varnothing}$}{Durchschnittliche Beleuchtungsstärke}
\nomenclature{$E_{\text{v},\varnothing}^{max}$}{Maximal zulässige durchschnittliche Beleuchtungsstärke}

\nomenclature{$AS$}{Anzahl der Startsvorgänge}
\nomenclature{$E_{Verlust} (t)$}{Verlustwärme des Gebäudes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
%\nomenclature{$\Delta T$}{Temperaturdifferenz}
\nomenclature{$A$}{Nutzfläche des Gebäudes}
\nomenclature{$k_{Verlust}$}{Proportionalitätskonstante für die Verlustwärme des Gebäudes}
\nomenclature{$T_{Au"s en} (t)$}{Außentemperatur zum Zeitpunkt (t)}
\nomenclature{$E_{NW} (t)$}{Benötigte Wärmenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{Soll}$}{Festgelegte Soll-Temperatur}
\nomenclature{$h$}{Etagenhöhe}
%\nomenclature{$\rho_{Luft}$}{Dichte von Luft}
\nomenclature{$c_{Luft}$}{Spezifische Wärmekapazität von Luft}
\nomenclature{$E_{Diff} (t)$}{Wärmeenergiedifferenz des Gebäudes zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{Heizung} (t)$}{Von der Heizung gelieferte Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{Klimaanlage} (t)$}{Von der Klimaanlage dem Gebäude entnommene Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{Sonstige} (t)$}{Vom menschlichen Körper und von den Haushaltsgeräten abgegebene Wärmeenergie zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$E_{max}$}{Maximale von der Heizung lieferbare Wärmeenergie für den Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{WS} (t)$}{Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$T_{WS,Heizen}^{min}$}{Für Heizaktivitäten minimal erforderliche Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{Gasverbrennung} (t)$}{Durch Gasverbrennung verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{Heizung} (t)$}{Durch Heizaktivitäten verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{Warmwasser} (t)$}{Durch den Warmwasserverbrauch verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{VerlustWS} (t)$}{Durch die Verlustwärme verursachte Temperaturänderung des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$\rho_{Wasser}$}{Dichte von Wasser}
\nomenclature{$c_{Wasser}$}{Spezifische Wärmekapazität von Wasser}
\nomenclature{$E_{Bereitschaft}(t)$}{Bereitschaftsverlust des Warmwasserspeichers zum Zeitpunkt $t$}
\nomenclature{$V_{Wassertank}$}{Volumen des Warmwasserspeichers}

\nomenclature{$k_{Bereitschaft}$}{Proportionalitätskonstante für den Bereitschaftsverlust}
\nomenclature{$\Delta T_{WS}$}{Temperaturdifferenz zwischen Warmwasserspeicher und der Raumtemperatur }
\nomenclature{$T_{WS}^{min}$}{Minimal zulässige Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers}
\nomenclature{$T_{WS}^{max}$}{Maximal zulässige Temperatur des Warmwasserspeichers}


\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I corrected the a_{i,j} and included the package amssymb. However nothing changed. Only a few of the entries (those which were shown at the beginning) are shown

Comment: @Noob: I am giving up on this: I've checked that there 141 entries in your example file and 130 of them appear in the output -- I've no idea what's happening with the remaining ones

Comment: In my document only 40 are shown

Comment: @Noob: Yes, we had this already ;-) I've have spend too much time on this

Comment: What would you advice me to do? Basically I wanted to do a nomenclature manually with align. My advicer said I should use the package nomenclature, but obviously this does not work.

Comment: I can't advice anything. There seems to be errors in your real document. I hope you do not have to submit it within the next days...

Comment: Unforunately I have to submit it tomorrow. This is why I am trying hard to solve the problem. But I think I cannot fix it.

Comment: Have you tried to generate the nomenclature `.nls` file manually with `makeindex ....` etc instead of using the `\write18{`... way?

Comment: No, I do not know how to do this

Comment: @Noob: It's described in the `nomenclature` file. `makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o foo.nls foo.nlo` if your document is called `foo.tex`

Comment: My documents name it thesis.tex and I do not understand what you want to explain. Where shall I add the command "makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o foo.nls foo.nlo"?

Comment: @Noob: Honestly, I get a little bit angry. I said if your document is called foo.tex then do it with foo, it's quite easy to replace the word foo with `thesis`, isn't it? And the makeindex command should be run in a terminal or command shell

Comment: I am sorry but this is the first time I have to work with Latex. And I do not know much about it and for me it is very difficult. For example - and I hope that this command does not make you very angry - I do not know what you mean with terminal or command shell.

Comment: Hi guys, Sorry I had to post my comment as an answer (which then was deleted) because I had an unregistered account and a registered one. I ask this question with the unregistered account and later I was not able to login with the unregistered account and I posted something with my registered account. Now I have merged the two accounts. My problem with the nomenclature, which is merely partially shown in the document, still exists. --> See next comment

Comment: I have still not solved the problem but I have found out something which is really striking. The .nlg and the .nlo files are not updated when I compile my document. The last time they were updated was yesterday during the afternoon. But I have added many nomenclature commands since then. I think this could explain why only about 40 entries out of more than 100 are shown in the document. What do you think?

Comment: Does nobody have an idea why the .nlg and .nlo files are not updated anymore?

Comment: This is the last time I will ask whether anyone would mind helping me. I have to submit my thesis in some hours, so this is probably my last question in this forum ever.

Comment: @Noob: I think we've provided as much help as possible. Fragments and and incomplete code by you aren't helpful for us. If you use a completely different setup -- how should we know this?

Comment: Although I was not able to include a nomenclature in my thesis because of this problem I want to thank you for your help.